# CSS Tooltip - Conversion from SCSS not working

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to get a CSS tooltip to work correctly which I found on the thoughtbot blog.  The only changes that I have made to the code is to change from Scss to CSS, and simplify the html a touch.  However, when in CSS, it doesnt work.

The original article can be found here, where there is also a working codepen that I copied as the basis for my CSS version https://robots.thoughtbot.com/you-don-t-need-javascript-for-that

```
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}



/* //The good stuff */
.tooltip-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}


/*   //Tooltip text container */
.tooltip-toggle::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: -80px;
  background-color: #2B222A;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip); 
  padding: 1rem;
  text-transform: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  width: 160px;
}
/* 
  //Tooltip arrow */
 .tooltip-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: 9px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #2B222A;
    content: " ";
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 0;
 }

.tooltip-toggle::before {
  color: #efefef;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip-toggle::after {
  color: #efefef;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: center;
}

/*   //Triggering the transition */
.tooltip-toogle:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
}
.tooltip-toggle:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
}
```

Below is my html.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container tooltip-toggle" data-tooltip="Sample text for your tooltip!>
      <div class="label">Hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I laughed very hard when I figured your problem out:

```
/*   //Triggering the transition */
.tooltip-toogle:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
}
```

.tooltip-**toogle**:hover

Obviously should be toggle, lol.

Edit: cleaned css and fixed it

```
.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}


/* The good stuff */
.tooltip-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

/* Tooltip text container */
.tooltip-toggle::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -80px;
    left: -80px;
    background-color: #2B222A;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    padding: 1rem;
    text-transform: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    width: 160px;
}

/* Tooltip arrow */
.tooltip-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: 9px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #2B222A;
    content: " ";
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 0;
}

.tooltip-toggle::before, .tooltip-toggle::after {
    color: #efefef;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-align: center;
}


/* Triggering the transition */

.tooltip-toogle:hover::before, .tooltip-toggle:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.75s ease;
}
```

Comment: No problem, accept it if it's correct ;) I've noticed you repeated a lot of css, you can easily group selectors together that use the same styles using a comma. See my edit above :)